# backslash in Yaml string

Tags: python, yaml

So I'm using yaml for some configuration files and py yaml to parse it.
For one field I have something like:

```
host: HOSTNAME\SERVER,5858
```

But when it gets parsed here what I get:

```
{
"host": "HOSTNAME\\SERVER,5858"
}
```

With 2 backslashes. I tried every combination of single quotes, double quotes, etc.
What's the best way to parse it correctly ?
Thanks

Comment: That's how backslashes are escaped on Python...

Comment: Does the yaml format important to the question?

Answer (score 9):

`len("\\") == 1`. What you see is the representation of the string as Python string literal. Backslash has special meaning in a Python literal e.g., `"\n"` is a single character (a newline). To get literal backslash in a string, it should be escaped `"\\"`.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't getting two backslashes. Python is displaying the single backslash as `\\` so that you don't think you've actually got a `\S` character (which doesn't exist... but e.g. `\n` does, and Python is trying to be as unambiguous as possible) in your string. Here's proof:

```
>>> data = {"host": "HOSTNAME\\SERVER,5858"}
>>> print(data["host"])
HOSTNAME\SERVER,5858
>>>
```

For more background, check out the documentation for [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr).